# Is there a way to make VLC time sync a video on separate computers, each having a local copy of the video?

Tags: video, sync, vlc-media-player

My friends and I are trying to watch a video that we all have on our machines, and would love to all have it timed together without the hassle of manually doing it. Is there a VLC plugin or tool that times it all together so that VLC plays the local file in sync with the other computers?

Comment: We are all apart from each other on different networks.

Comment: Set up the audio conference. Have everyone start the video file and hit _pause_ when it starts to fade up from black, or at the studio logo. When everyone's ready "...3...2...1..PLAY"

Answer (score 0):

https://www.howtogeek.com/118075/how-to-stream-videos-and-music-over-the-network-using-vlc/

I have not done it before i just found it, there is an other option that i will try to mplayer

http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/HTML/en/networksync.html

Comment: If i port-forward or any other technique to sync up the other pcs, will this do the trick?

Comment: yes if the other computer it is not in your local network surely you need to port-forward to do the trick but you will be limited by the speed of the connection but now anything up to 5 m/s its good to stream good look ;)